# Am I using the word 'leverage' correctly ?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage, contemporary-english

The sentence is, "I want to leverage my understanding of topic A with the knowledge of topic B to prepare myself well for a particular career".

I want to convey that I already know topic A and learning topic B will be a huge add-on if I want to choose a particular career.

Can you suggest me a better way of conveying the idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off using *leverage* as a noun. Most dictionaries define it first as a noun ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leverage), [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=leverage), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/leverage), etc.), and only second as a verb (and dubiously at that - AH and MW both define the verb form as "to provide something with leverage").

There also appears to be a raging internet argument around the use of "leverage" as a verb (and its general overuse). You can see related discussions at [Pain in the English](https://painintheenglish.com/case/5392) and [Fluent](https://this.isfluent.com/blog/2010/are-you-stupid-enough-to-use-leverage-as-a-verb/) (prepare yourself for the latter - the title of the article is "Are You Stupid Enough to Use Leverage as a Verb?").

A better construction of your sentence would be something like the following:

> Supplementing your understanding of topic A with knowledge of topic B could give you leverage over other applicants for a job in a particular career field.

Here's a specific example off the top of my head:

> Supplementing your proficiency in Adobe Illustrator with knowledge of basic graphic design principles would give you leverage over other applicants for the Magazine Editor position.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bryan! 'Supplement' seems the right word.

Comment: How does this sound to you ? By reinforcing my existing understanding of topic A with that of topic B, I hope to better prepare myself for a particular career.

Comment: It sounds pretty good, but I think you want to add "knowledge of" before topic B, i.e., "By reinforcing my existing understanding of topic A with knowledge of topic B, I hope to better prepare myself for a particular career." With your current construction, the "_that_ of topic B" is actually saying "_existing understanding_ of topic B."
(Edit: still learning how to comment!)

Comment: In my case topic A and B are completely independent of each other, but they somehow help in improving a particular career path. I am just afraid that the word 'reinforce' will indicate the topics A and B are complementary to one another, which they are not.

Comment: Hmm... are you 'reinforcing' _both_ topics A and B, or ? Saying that you're reinforcing your existing understanding _with that_ of topic B implies that the two are connected; i.e., a better understanding of topic B [reinforces](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinforce), or makes stronger, your understanding of topic A (which probably won't happen if both A and B are independent of one another). Perhaps "By reinforcing my existing understanding of topic A and topic B, I hope to better prepare myself for a particular career." would be more accurate?

Comment: Please have a look at my car mechanic example below. I don't need reinforcement in topic A (tires), since I am a pro, but I am a complete newbie in topic B(engines), so there's nothing to reinforce. What can I do now ?

Comment: Neither _leverage_ nor _reinforce_ will work for your purposes; both of those would imply that learning topic B would somehow improve your knowledge of topic A. If you're looking to say that you know topic A, but learning topic B in addition would make you a better candidate, I'd suggest the following: "I want to add experience with engine maintenance to my existing knowledge of tires in order to better prepare myself for a career as a car mechanic."

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to [leverage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/leverage) my understanding of topic A with the knowledge of
>   topic B to prepare myself well for a particular career".

**to leverage**, verb [ T ] (USE)
​

> to use something that you already have in order to achieve something
>   new or better; to improve or enhance:

My sense is that your use of **leverage** as in your sample sentence is grammatical and appropriate. To **[enhance](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/enhance)** would do nicely too.

enhance:

> make better or more attractive, to increase

Comment: Your citation implies that 'leverage' is used for help something with something you already have. The OP is just adding on topic B.

Comment: @Mitch  The knowledge of X help the understanding of Y.  Does not having X leverage the learning Y?

Comment: "I want to leverage my understanding of tires with the knowledge of engines to better prepare myself for a career as a car mechanic", I don't think I am using leverage correctly here. How do I say that I already know an important part of a system and want to learn about another part, thus I want to make myself a better mechanic.

Comment: "I want to leverage my understanding of Latin to gain knowledge of Medicine to prepare myself well for as a nurse practitioner particular ".